# Создание shared_ptr через make_shared и через new

Tags: c++

Создание `std::shared_ptr` через `std::make_shared` может быть полезным в следующем случае:

```
boo(std::shared_ptr<Bar>(new Bar), foo());
```

здесь может быть утечка, если `foo` бросит исключение, и

```
boo(std::make_shared<Bar>(), foo());
```

исключит утечку памяти.

Вопрос: в общем случае, например

```
 std::shared_ptr<Bar> pBar(new Bar);
```

лучше использовать `new` или использовать `std::make_shared`?

Comment: у make_shared есть один большой недостаток. если объект большой, shared_ptr живет недолго, а связанные weak_ptr - долго, то память будет занята, что может быть нежелательным. Ну и кастомные делитеры...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Из Скотт Мейерс - "Эффективный и современный С++ 11/14" (глава 4.4):

> Особенностью std::make_shared (по сравнению с непосредственным использованием new) является повышенная эффективность. Применение std::make_shared позволяет
> компиляторам генерировать меньший по размеру и более быстрый код, использующий
> более компактные структуры данных.

Там написано достаточно детально (рекомендую почитать), но вкратце в случае

```
std::shared_ptr<Bar> pBar(new Bar);
```

произойдет 2 выделения памяти: одно для `new Bar`, другое для управляющего блока умного указателя.

В случае же

```
auto pBar = std::make_shared<Bar>();
```

может быть выполнено одно выделение с последующим размещением объекта `Bar` в управляющем блоке умного указателя. Таким образом количество выделений памяти может быть сокращено до одного.

Что именно попадет в исполняемый файл зависит от оптимизаций компилятора.

В целом же автор рекомендует:

> предпочитайте использование std::make_unique и std::make_shared непосредственному использованию оператора new

Comment: или костыльте свой raii )))